# Scraping an url using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hello I am beginner in data scraping.
At this case I want to get an url like "https:// . . ." but the result is a list in link variable that contain of all links in web. Here the code below;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.detik.com/search/searchall?query=KPK'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
artikel = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'list media_rows list-berita'})
p = 1
link = []
for p in artikel:
     s = p.findAll('a', href=True)['href']
     link.append(s)
```

the result of the code above is getting error such as

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-469cb6eabf70> in <module>
3 link = []
4 for p in artikel:
5         s = p.findAll('a', href=True)['href']
6         link.append(s)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The result is I want to get all links of https:// . . . in <div class = 'list media_rows list-berita' as a list
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please can you include error message in the question?

Comment: i think the error could be in artikel variable, because i checked it from the len(artikel) is only 1. So, it's not a list. the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: i request please include the error message with your question, Full Traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.detik.com/search/searchall?query=KPK'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
articles = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'list media_rows list-berita'})
links = []

for article in articles:
    
    hrefs = article.find_all('a', href=True)
    for href in hrefs:
        links.append(href['href'])
        
print(links)
```

Output:

```
['https://news.detik.com/kolom/d-5609578/bahaya-laten-narasi-kpk-sudah-mati', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609585/penyuap-nurdin-abdullah-tawarkan-proyek-sulsel-ke-pengusaha-minta-rp-1-m', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609537/7-gebrakan-ahok-yang-bikin-geger', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609423/ppp-minta-bkn-jangan-asal-sebut-twk-kpk-dokumen-rahasia', 
'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609382/mantan-sekjen-nasdem-gugat-pasal-suap-ke-mk-karena-dinilai-multitafsir', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609381/kpk-gali-informasi-soal-nurdin-abdullah-beli-tanah-pakai-uang-suap', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609378/hrs-bandingkan-kasus-dengan-pinangki-ary-askhara-tuntutan-ke-saya-gila', 'https://news.detik.com/detiktv/d-5609348/pimpinan-kpk-akhirnya-penuhi-panggilan-komnas-ham', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5609286/wakil-ketua-kpk-nurul-ghufron-penuhi-panggilan-komnas-ham-soal-polemik-twk']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `div` with the class `list media_rows list-berita`. So you can use `find` instead of `findAll`

1. Select the `div` with class name `list media_rows list-berita`
2. Select all the `<a>` with `findAll` from the `div`. This will give you a list of all `<a>` tags present inside the `div`
3. Iterate over all the `<a>` from the above list and extract the `href`.

Here is a working code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.detik.com/search/searchall?query=KPK'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
artikel = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'list media_rows list-berita'})
a_hrefs = artikel.findAll('a')
link = []
for k in a_hrefs:
     link.append(k['href'])

print(link)
```